# Failure to propagate Windows environment changes using SendMessage and WM_SETTINGCHANGE

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry, environment-variables

I'm interested in the programmatic update and propagation to the system, of the Windows environment variables, using C/C++. (Let's assume I know how to *change* the variables.) The Microsoft Support article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/104011) suggests using `SendMessageTimeout` and `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` to enact the crucial propagation of such changes to the system at large; and it's clear online that this approach is well used; with minor variations such as differing timeout periods. I find for most situations this solution indeed works as advertised. However, I have an exception which I'll describe below.

[image: The Windows Environment Variable Panel]

The non-programmatic, GUI method of updating a Windows environment variable is using the "Environment Variable" panel; shown above. Environment variables can be modified by adding or editing the relevant fields. This is followed with the propagation step, which here can easily be accomplished by clicking the "OK" button.

Environment variables are stored within the Windows registry. For simplicity, and to minimise the chance of an error in the programming stages, the Windows regedit.exe GUI tool is introduced here. Within regedit.exe, both User and System environment variables can be located at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` respectively; and edited. Following an edit, here in regedit.exe, propagation to the system must still be enacted; and can be achieved in a few ways: for example, **a)** again simply clicking "OK" on the "Environment Variables" panel pictured above; or **b)** sending a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message using the `SendMessageTimeout` function. I find the second method lacking when used as part of the following recipe:

1. Create a *new* System environment variable of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` in regedit.exe. Name it "APATH", and set it; e.g. to C:\dev
2. Update the existing System environment variable, "Path", to reference the new variable at its tail. e.g. ...PowerShell\v1.0\;%APATH%
3. **Propagate the changes**, using either method **a)** or **b)** from above.
4. Examine the expansion of %APATH% within %Path% by typing "path" at a fresh instance of the cmd.exe command prompt.

I find that with method **a)** the %APATH% variable is expanded; while with method **b)** it is not. Does anyone know how to perform the actions performed by method **a)** (clicking "OK" on the Environment Variables panel) at the C/C++ programming level?

Comment: You haven't mentioned which parameters you're using when you send `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`. `wParam == 0` and `lParam == L"Environment"` should be all you need.

Comment: Yes, those are the parameters I use. As I said, for most situations it works fine, but not for the example I provide.

Comment: Do you ensure regedit.exe flushes the changes to the registry? E.g. do you open another key there or close Registry Editor at all before sending the message?

Comment: Closing regedit.exe makes no difference to the situation.

Comment: Sending a  `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message with `lParam == L"Environment"` causes Explorer to execute `shell32!RegenerateUserEnvironment`, which you can verify by attaching a debugger. The updated environment will be inherited by a child process, such as a new cmd shell. The control panel app updates the environment values in the registry and sends the same message.

Comment: @eryksun Do you know why the two methods give a different outcome? Are you able to replicate my result?

Comment: Thanks for the input @eryhsun. Sounds interesting - I think you're saying that issuing the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message from Python on its own would not propagate changes made elsewhere; say in regedit.exe. But, when such changes are made within the same Python session, your version of the experiment passes. I wish I could learn from what your Python script is doing differently at the winapi level; as I mentioned, I get the same result if I work entirely at the winapi C/C++ level; i.e. avoiding regedit.exe.

Comment: @user2023370: I believe eryksun is talking about Windows sessions (aka Remote Desktop sessions, aka Terminal Services sessions) rather than Python sessions.  This basically just means that if two users are logged in simultaneously, the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message will only affect the user that sent it, not the other user.  Similarly, if a system service (e.g., a web server, psexec, etc.) broadcasts the message, that won't affect the logged-on user.

Comment: If you'll post complete code for your test application I'll see whether I can reproduce the problem or not.

Comment: I'm working with Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 machines. The program is not running as a service. I will attempt to extract a useful portion of code.

Comment: The library at https://github.com/dmoulding/editenv.git can be used; it's nice, but not alone in demonstrating the issue. A main.cpp which links to it can be defined which makes two function calls: `envSet(editenv::es_system, "ANAME", "C:\\dev"); envPaste(editenv::es_system, "Path", ";%ANAME%");`.

Comment: I open a new instance of cmd.exe. As I mentioned, I've tried minor variations such as differing timeout periods. In the absence of any other ideas, it would be useful if the result could at least be replicated.

Comment: Thankyou for trying that @eryksun. The problem I am presenting is however obtained by a different sequence than the one you followed. It is crucial that `APATH` is a *new* System environment variable. (Once `APATH` is recognised by the system, I too observe *subsequent* updates through `cmd.exe`.) That is, if you begin with no `APATH`, then execute the `envSet` and `envPaste` commands I mentioned above, perhaps you will see the effect.

Comment: Thanks for the input @eryksun, let's wait and see if anyone else can contribute.

Comment: I think this may be a variant of http://superuser.com/a/823802/96662 ; although in this case the reference isn't really recursive, using REG_EXPAND_SZ instead of REG_SZ may have a similar effect.  What happens on your system if you use REG_SZ instead of REG_EXPAND_SZ when creating APATH?

Comment: Although undocumented, the issue you link to (the example there isn't actually recursive btw.) concerns a somewhat understood limitation of Windows environment variables, wherein a REG_EXPAND_SZ variable referenced from another REG_EXPAND_SZ variable must precede it alphabetically; n.b. APATH precedes Path. Regarding REG_SZ variables in my example, with APATH as an REG_SZ, the propagation executes correctly using either method.

Comment: The control panel dialog uses `REG_SZ` if the value doesn't have at least two "%" symbols. `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values get expanded in order of enumeration. Dependencies should be avoided if possible, since `RegEnumValue` lists values in arbitrary set order. The control panel dialog works around this by rewriting the environment key. It first enumerates the key to delete all of the `REG_SZ` and `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values. Then it sets the alphabetically ordered values from the dialog box.

Comment: I added comments to the answer at http://superuser.com/a/823802 that correct the incorrect assumption on the enumeration order of values in a registry key. It's the insertion order, not alphabetic order.

Comment: @eryksun Very interesting. I never guessed it might work that way. I'll try that using the editenv library and see if it works for the original `APATH` problem.